# making sure that iptables is running

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, monitoring

Is there a tool for monitoring that iptables (or shorewall or similar) is up and running with a core set of important rules? I need something which alerts me either if the firewall goes donw completely, or if one of a number of rules isn't active anymore, for whatever reason.

I don't want to try the functionality of the firewall by connecting to the ports or (worse) checking if others are connecting.

Server: debian wheezy, standard install. Let's say I want to check that port 80 rule is open for the world and port 8080 only for a certain ip a.b.c.d.

One way would be to save the working rules as a textfile and then have a daily cron job which compares the current rules with this original one, but I'm hoping there's something else that I can use. Is it possible to achieve this in munin or nagios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) tool for basic or [hping3](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hping3) for more advanced security auditing of your firewall rules. This nmap command run remotely against your firewall can test your firewall's rulesets:

```
nmap -p 0-65535 -Pn FIREWALL_HOST
```

Or you can implement a kind of auditing with iptables `LOG` target extension to log everything what wasn't matched with previous rules:

```
# firewal rulesets
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.5 -j ACCEPT
....
....
....
# this rule will log everything suspicious not matched before
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG 
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Finally, your idea to compare a dump of rulesets is not bad as well. You can use `diff` for it and then to check return code  of the command:

```
iptables -L -n > RULESET_FILE


if ! diff RULESETS_FILE <(iptables -L -n) > RULESETS_CHANGES; then
   echo "Rulesets changed"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Of your three answers, I like nmap most and the third with the diff.

Comment: Bitbox, welcome to SF.  I hope you'll forgive me mentioning that local etiquette is that, when you're happy with an answer, you accept it by clicking the tick outline next to it; this drives the SF reputation system both for you and the author of your preferred answer.  My apologies if you already knew that.

Comment: @MadHatter no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

try to compare

```
iptabes-save
```

and startup config (/etc/sysconfig/iptables, etc). If all ok - this should be identical.